# Proof of $\sum_{k=n-1}^{n+p-1} {k \choose p}={n+p \choose p}$ using the equation $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n = p$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

So we consider the following equation: $$x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n = p$$ We dnote the set of solutions (lists of $\{0, \dots ,p \}$) by $A(n,p)$.
If we write $p=1+1+\dots+1$ then the problem can be reduced to putting p indistinguishable balls in $n$ ordered containers, or in other words, how many ways there are to arrange the inner $n-1$ walls of our containers and the $p$ digits.
Thus $$|A(n,p)|={n+p-1\choose p}$$
I'm trying to use this to prove the equation $$\sum_{k=n-1}^{n+p-1} {k \choose p}={n+p \choose p}$$
The RHS is the cardinality of $A(n+1, p)$, and we can count its elements by looking at the possible values of $x_{n+1}$, this give: $$\sum_{x_{n+1}=0}^{p}|A(n, p-x_{n+1})|=\sum_{x_{n+1}=0}^{p}{n+p-x_{n+1}-1\choose p-x_{n+1}}$$
But my book writes it as: $$\sum_{x_{n+1}=0}^{p}{n+p-x_{n+1}-1\choose p}$$
Where is the error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your expression looks right to me.  The book's is clearly wrong.  Try substituting $n=2,\ p=5.$

Comment: Your solution looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your book's equation
$$
\sum_{k=n-1}^{n+p-1}\binom{k}{\color{red}p}=\binom{n+p}{p}
$$
is incorrect. However, 
$$
\sum_{k=n-1}^{n+p-1}\binom{k}{\color{#080}{n-1}}=\binom{n+p}p
$$
is correct. With this, everything works smoothly:
\begin{align}
\binom{n+p}{p}
&=A(n+1,p)
\\&=\sum_{x_{n+1}=0}^p A(n,p-x_{n+1})
\\&=\sum_{x_{n+1}=0}^p \binom{n+(p-x_{n+1})-1}{p-x_{n+1}}
\\\\&(\text{reindex summation by }{k=n+p-x_{n+1}-1})\\
\\&=\sum_{k=n-1}^{n+p-1}\binom{k}{k-(n-1)}
\\&=\sum_{k=n-1}^{n+p-1}\binom{k}{n-1}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, it's often hard to imagine that the book is wrong, especially when I'm still struggling.